# Smart rewriting of expressions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, equation

I found this to be tricky to explain, but I'll do my best through an example.

Consider the expression assigned to the variable `grad` below

```
 from sympy import *

 a, x, b = symbols("a x b")    
 y_pred = a * x    
 loss = log(1 + exp(- b * y_pred))
 grad = diff(loss, x, 1)
```

`grad` has the following expression:

```
-a*b*exp(-a*b*x)/(1 + exp(-a*b*x))
```

Now I want to manipulate `grad` in two ways.

1) I want `sympy` to try rewrite the expression `grad` such that none of its terms look like

`exp(-a*b*x)/(1 + exp(-a*b*x))`.

2) I also want it to try to rewrite the expression such that it has at least one term that look like this `1./(1 + exp(a*b*x))`.

So at the end, `grad` becomes:

```
-a*b/(1 + exp(a*b*x)
```

Note that `1./(1 + exp(a*b*x))` is equivalent to `exp(-a*b*x)/(1 + exp(-a*b*x))` but I don't want to mention that to `sympy` explicitly :).

I'm not sure if this is feasible at all, but it would be interesting to know whether it's possible to do this to some extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cancel` does this

```
In [16]: cancel(grad)
Out[16]:
  -a⋅b
──────────
 a⋅b⋅x
ℯ      + 1
```

This works because it sees the expression as `-a*b*(1/A)/(1 + 1/A)`, where `A = exp(a*b*x)`, and `cancel` rewrites rational functions as canceled `p/q` (see the section on [cancel](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#cancel) in the SymPy tutorial for more information).

Note that this only works because it uses `A = exp(a*b*x)` instead of `A = exp(-a*b*x)`. So for instance, `cancel` won't do the similar simplification here

```
In [17]: cancel(-a*b*exp(a*b*x)/(1 + exp(a*b*x)))
Out[17]:
      a⋅b⋅x
-a⋅b⋅ℯ
────────────
  a⋅b⋅x
 ℯ      + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for `simplify`?

```
>>> grad
-a*b*exp(-a*b*x)/(1 + exp(-a*b*x))
>>> simplify(grad)
-a*b/(exp(a*b*x) + 1)
```

Comment: right, it seems that `simplify` works in this case because the simplest form has `1/(1+exp(a*b*x))`, but would it be possible for `sympy` to try rewrite an expression in terms of some specific user-defined sub-expression in the best that it can?  it would be like Google search where you can enforce which terms should appear or not appear in the search results. I can update the question to provide an example where simplify didn't work.

Comment: Well, instead of using `simplify` directly, you can also use the specific simplifications you need (`powsimp`? `radsimp`? `together`? `logcombine`? `cancel`? ...) If that's not what you mean, then I have no idea, I'm relatively new to Sympy